# Regex not ended in html

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches with a text like `/es/whathever1/whathever2/whatever3` and not ends with html

I tried with :

```regex
\/es\/.*[aA-zZ\-\_]\/.*[aA-zZ\-\_]\/.*[aA-zZ\-\_].*[.]html$.*$
```

but only matches if ends with `.html`

Comment: This will match it `^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/blUygJ/1 Using `aA-zZ` in a character class in not the same as A-Za-z. And note that you actually are matching `.html` at the end.

Comment: `^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+)+$` matches with `/whathever` and `whatever/whatever` it only has to match with thre sections

Comment: Then you can try `^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+){3}$` https://regex101.com/r/eGUrLN/1

Answer (score 2):

Using the character class `[aA-zZ\-\_]` matches a single character of one  of the listed. It is not the same as `[a-zA-Z]` as A-z [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) characters.

You can repeat 3 times matching `/` and 1+ word characters using a quantifier and add anchors for the start `^` and end `$` of the string to prevent a partial match

```
^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+){3}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGUrLN/1)

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think they're trying to match path names of files. And they just want to not match .html files. So f.ex. .txt and .pdf should still be a match.

Comment: @Scratte I would not know about that part. If I remembered correctly, the OP replied that it worked but Is don't see that comment anymore now.

Comment: I think that is your regex: [Redirect adding .html on .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67986281/redirect-adding-html-on-htaccess)

Comment: @Scratte Ah, it is :-) Let it then be 2 separate questions to not mix answers.