# Redirect adding .html on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm using this regex o redirect in .htaccess file to the same url adding .html at the end

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+){3}$ $1.html
```

If I don't use `$1` there is no error , I don't know what is wrong

I tried with this too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/es(?:\/[\w-]+){3}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

but it does nothing

Comment: Could you also give an example url? Is the path starting with `/es`?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown attempts, to do internal rewrite please try following Rules set in your .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Please make sure your htacces file is present in root.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^es(?:/[\w-]+){3}/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Either use above OR following rules only at a time. In case you want to redirect on browser then try following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^es(?:/[\w-]+){3}/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```